# iPod4 (iOS6) shows wrong iPhone5 launch image

Tags: ios6, splash-screen, ipod, iphone-5, uilaunchimagefile

To my iPhones app's XCode project I have added the following launch images:

- Default~iphone.png
- Default~iphone@2x.png
- Default~iphone-568h@2x.png

On the iPhone4, iPhone4s and iPhone5 the correct launch image is shown. 
Also XCode's project summary tells me that every thing is ok with the launch images.

But if I launch the app on my iPod4 then the iPhone5 splash screen (Default~iphone-568h@2x.png) and not the iPhone4 screen (Default~iphone.png) is shown. There is iOS6 installed on my iPod.

Any idea, what's wrong here?

Comment: The discussion in the apple developer forum: https://devforums.apple.com/message/741488

Answer (score 2):

The files above have wrong names. They should be:

- Default~iphone.png
- Default@2x~iphone.png
- Default-568h@2x~iphone.png

But giving the files the right names is not enough. You should:

- Look into the info.plist file of your app, that there are the right launch images set
- The wrongly named image Default~iphone-568h@2x.png can remain in the application bundle, even if you delete and reinstall the app. Thus it can be that the changes above have no effect.
- To prevent this I had to delete my app, clean and recompile my XCode project and reboot my device. After that everything worked fine.